# How to setup Wordpress Pretty Permalink on shared IIS7 hosting with no url rewrite module installed

Tags: iis-7, wordpress, shared-hosting, permalinks

I have setup Wordpress blog v2.9.2 on my website at location www.22shruti.com/blog/
(Shared IIS 7.0 Hosting (no admin rights on the server), PHP 5.2.13 FastCGI, WHB Operating System 2008, no url rewrite module installed.)

Since pretty permalinks are useful from SEO perspective, when I try to change the WP Permalink setting to a custom "/%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%/" via admin, I get following message on www.22shruti.com/blog/

"Not Found Sorry, but you are looking for something that isn't here."

What is the step by step solution to achieve the desired permalink format in this scenario? Help is much appreciated.

p.s. I contacted my hosting tech. support and the answer I have received is : "custom 404 url from our end is currently not possible as URL rewritng in Plesk panel is not allowed". Any other workaround / alternative in the given scenario? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might point the 404 error document to a specially crafted php file which will do mapping and redirection for you.
But since this would always return status 404 to clients there is no gain from a SEO perspective.

Comment: Thanks pacey. I contacted my hosting tech. support and the answer I have received is : "custom 404 url from our end is currently not possible as URL rewritng in Plesk panel is not allowed". So any other workaround / alternative in the given scenario? Thanks.